# Sending meeting invites from another email address

Tags: vba, outlook

I am using tool coded in VBA to send meeting invites in bunch.  [meeting invite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTI3J.png)

When I use an email address, that I added to Outlook first, everything works.

When I use another email address that I added to Outlook after it, I get this message:

> "Sending account 'invitation@gmail.com' not found."

I paste the email address, invitation@gmail.com, from which I want to send meeting invitations in sh.cell(1,2).

The part of the code that is giving me the message:

```vb
Dim currentAccount As Outlook.Account
Dim acc As Outlook.Account

For Each currentAccount In AppOutlook.Session.Accounts
    If currentAccount.SmtpAddress = sht.Cells(1, 2) Then
        Set acc = currentAccount
        FoundAccount = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next

If Not FoundAccount Then
    MsgBox "Sending account '" & sht.Cells(1, 2) & "' not found."
    Exit Sub
End If
```

How can I set up invitation@gmail.com as my current account?

I can provide the rest of the code, but my assumption is that I have to set up something in Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

Your code indicates the email address is not an account.

Outlook documentation typically refers to email addresses / mailboxes as accounts.

Outlook VBA requires accounts to be added like this:

[Add an email account to Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-an-email-account-to-outlook-6e27792a-9267-4aa4-8bb6-c84ef146101b).

[image]