# Unable to get Microsoft Outlook Account using VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-access-2016

I am trying to get Emails from a folder in Microsoft Outlook from a VBA module in Microsoft Outlook. This just fine for one of my accounts, but not for another.

Only one account is available when I set the namespace object, even though I can see three in Outlook.

Any ideas why some accounts would not show up would be appreciated.

```
Public Function get_Outlook_Account_By_Name(strMailboxName As String) As outlook.Account
    Dim olApp As outlook.application
    Dim olNamespace As outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olAccount As outlook.Account
    
    Set olApp = New outlook.application
    Set olNamespace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    For Each olAccount In olNamespace.Accounts
        If olAccount.DisplayName = strMailboxName Then
            Set get_Outlook_Account_By_Name = olAccount
            Exit For
        End If
    Next olAccount
    
    Set olApp = Nothing
    Set olNamespace = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: What does your debugger say is inside `olNamespace.Accounts`?

Comment: So what exactly fails? Does `olAccount.DisplayName` match your value in `strMailboxName`?

Comment: I only get one of my three email accounts showing up in olNamespace.Accounts. So it's not that the strings don't match, it's that there is just one account in that collection. I'm wondering if it's how the accounts are set up, but I cannot the what the difference is.

Comment: Turns out these might be set up as shared mailboxes. I'm looking into that.

Comment: Right, Shared Mailboxes in Exchange don't constitute a separate mailbox "Account" as far as Outlook is concerned.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73457951/1571407. The link there points to a Microsoft page https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-an-email-account-to-outlook-6e27792a-9267-4aa4-8bb6-c84ef146101b?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us